# kivymd: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, mobile-application, kivymd

This .kv file I lode the Kivy file by `Builder.load_file('style.kv')`

```
 ScreenManager:
      Sign_in:
      Sign_up:

<Sign_in>:
    name: 'sign in'
    MDScreen:
       id: sign_in
       md_bg_color: [35/255, 59/255, 54/255, 1]
       MDCard:
          size_hint: None, None
          size: 320, 400
          pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.5}
          elevation: 15
          md_bg_color: [35/255, 49/255, 48/255, 1]
          padding: 20
          spacing: 30
          orientation: "vertical"
          MDLabel:
              text: "LOGIN"
              font_style: 'Button'
              font_size: 45
              halign: "center"
              size_hint_y: None
              height: self.texture_size[1]
              padding_y: 15
          MDTextFieldRound:
              id: username
              hint_text: "username"
              icon_right: "account"
              size_hint_x: None
              width: 220
              pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
              color_active: [1,1,1,1]
          MDTextFieldRound:
              id: Pass
              hint_text: "Password"
              icon_right: "eye-off"
              size_hint_x: None
              width: 220
              pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
              password: True
              color_active: [1,1,1,1]
          MDTextFieldRound:
              id: Email
              hint_text: "Email Id"
              icon_right: "email"
              size_hint_x: None
              width: 220
              pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
              password: True
              color_active: [1,1,1,1]
          MDRoundFlatButton:
              text: "Sign In"
              pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
              font_size: 15
              on_press: app.show_data()
          Widget:
              size_hint_y: None
              height: 30
<Sign_up>:
    name: 'sign up'
```

I tried lot of things but nothing solve this error  **.py file** how to solve it?

[image]

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class Sign_in(Screen):
    pass


class Sign_up(Screen):
    pass

se = ScreenManager()
se.add_widget(Sign_in(name='sign in'))
se.add_widget(Sign_up(name='sign up'))


class Chatting(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('style.kv')

    def show_data(self):
        print(self.root.ids.username.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Chatting().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code:

```
print(self.root.ids.username.text)
```

is trying to access the `username` `id` through the root widget of your `App`, but the root widget is `ScreenManager` which does not contain that `id`. According to your `kv`, the `username` `id` is defined in the `Sign_in` widget.

You can access the `username` `Screen` widget using the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager` like this:

```
print(self.root.get_screen('sign in').ids.username.text)
```

Note that the lines:

```
se = ScreenManager()
se.add_widget(Sign_in(name='sign in'))
se.add_widget(Sign_up(name='sign up'))
```

are creating another widget tree that is not actually used in your `App`. The widget tree that is used is built by the line:

```
return Builder.load_file('style.kv')
```

so those three lines above can be eliminated.

Comment: thank you for you help which clear my error

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would like to add to any future researchers is to add self. to any variable that you're passing.

For example, if you wanted to pass a variable in your widget to your app, you must declare the variable in the app as self.some_variable = self.self.root.get_screen('sign in').ids.username.text. You can then use this variable to perform functions.

In the above code, you may want to compare username.text to a username that you have stored. If you make your variable in your app some_variable = self.root.get_screen('sign in').ids.username.text, it will give you the same error.

This took me days to figure out, so I hope it helps someone someday.